# OOP accessing method from non-related class

Tags: oop, mvvm, architecture

Hello Stackoverflowers,

I have 5 classes, Foo, Bar, Thud, Grunt, Zot. 
Thud and Grunt instances are field of Bar. Foo instance is a field of Thud.

Foo, Thud and Grunt prepare data for a View (MVVM pattern, they are the view model). Foo and Zot are the datas or create them (the model)

Among other things, Foo produce some Zot listed in Grunt (added from Bar, who access Foo from Thud). I need Foo to get the list of Zot in Grunt. If possible i would like to avoid going all the work (will serialize the list) in the Grunt or the Bar class because they are not the model. The process will always start from Foo (adding new classes or stuff is of course possible)

```
public class Bar
{
  Thud thud;
  Grunt grunt;

  Bar(Zot zotInstance)
  {
    new thud();
    new grunt();
    grunt.zotlist.add(zotInstance);
  }
 }

public class Thud
{
  Foo foo;
}

public class Grunt
{
  list<Zot> zotList;
  public list<Zot> getList();
}
public class Foo
{
  public Zot makeZots() {};
  public void BringMeZots() // I would like a way to get the zotList when this method is called.
}
```

I'm not sure to explain it in the simplest way. Tell me if another explanation of my problem is needed.

Answer (score 0):

So you need a way to share the `Grunt` object you're creating.

First you need a way to inject this into your `Foo` class:

```
public class Foo
{
  Grunt grunt;

  public Foo(Grunt g)
  {
    grunt = g;
  }

  public Zot makeZots()
  {
  }

  public void BringMeZots()
  {
    List<Zot> hereAreSomeZots = grunt.getList();
  }
}
```

Which means you need to inject it into your `Thud` class also:

```
public class Thud
{
  Foo foo;

  public Thud(Grunt g)
  {
    foo = new Foo(g);
  }
}
```

Then lastly, you can pass this `Grunt` instance into your `Thud` instance:

```
public class Bar
{
  Thud thud;
  Grunt grunt;

  Bar(Zot zotInstance)
  {
    grunt = new Grunt();
    grunt.zotlist.add(zotInstance);
    thud = new Thud(grunt);
  }
}
```

You have pretty abstract class names so it's difficult for me to tell what each of these is actually doing but normally when I see dependencies needing to be passed around this much, it signals issues with the overall design.

You should look at dependency injection as this will also simplify your design.